# Cannot increment a simple value in redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am very new to react and redux and still trying to wrap my head around basics.
I need to use boilerplate for the project that is upcoming, where redux is split in different folders and files  -  actions, reduces, store. Like so:

```
Redux
├── actions
│   ├── actionTypes.js
│   ├── counterActions.js // created by me
│   └── usersActions.js
├── reducers
│   ├── counterReducer.js // created by me
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── initialState.js
│   └── usersReducer.js
└── store
    └── configureStore.js
```

So here, I am simply trying to display data from my store to my app and manipulate it with a button clicks (increment, decrement).
Here is my files content:

./actions/actionTypes:

```
export const GET_REQUESTER_SUCCESS = 'GET_REQUESTER_SUCCESS';
export const COUNTER_INCREMENT = 'COUNTER_INCREMENT';
export const COUNTER_DECREMENT = 'COUNTER_DECREMENT';
```

./actions/counterActions:

```
import * as types from './actionTypes'

export const counterIncrement = () => {
    return {
        type: types.COUNTER_INCREMENT,
    }
}

export const counterDecrement = () => {
    return {
        type: types.COUNTER_DECREMENT,
    }
}
```

./reducers/counterReducer.js:

```
import * as types from "../actions/actionTypes";
import initialState from "./initialState";

export default function changeCounter(state = initialState.counter, action) {
  switch (action.types) {
    case types.COUNTER_INCREMENT:
      console.log('increment')
      return state + 1
    case types.COUNTER_DECREMENT:
      console.log('decrement')
      return state - 1
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

./reducers/initialState.js:

```
export default {
  users: {},
  counter: 0,
};
```

All the reducers are then combined in the ./reducers/index.js files:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import users from './usersReducer';
import changeCounter from './counterReducer'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  users,
  changeCounter,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

And last but not least, snippet of the App where I am displaying and trying to increment my counter:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import './App.scss';
import { connect, useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld'
import { counterIncrement } from './redux/actions/counterActions';


function App(props) {
  const { users } = props;
  const { requester = {} } = users;
  const counter = useSelector(state => state.changeCounter)
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <HelloWorld />
      <p>Counter is {counter}</p>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(counterIncrement())}>+</button>
      <button>-</button>
```

So, as far as I understand - my reducer is created, it is combined with another one (comes with boilerplate and works well).  I am dispatching an action (which I can see in redux dev tool being dispatched), but my reducer is just not doing an increment.

What would be the reason for that.
Please let me know if I provided insufficient information.

Comment: This is just a typographic error. It will not help for other readers of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's typo mistake, change `types` to `type` :

In `./reducers/counterReducer.js`

```
export default function changeCounter(state = initialState.counter, action) {
  switch (action.types) { // <----- ISSUE
```

change it to :

```
export default function changeCounter(state = initialState.counter, action) {
  switch (action.type) { //<---- CHANGE
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-react-redux-issue?file=index.js)**

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I am not sure if I followed your instructions correctly though, but once changed it to const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  users,
  counter: changeCounter,
});

export default rootReducer;
I now cannot even see  my store in redux dev tool. and increment still does not work

Comment: @OlegGulevskyy, is it possible to create a working demo on stackblitz?

Comment: Apologies, I can see the store still, but it does not change the behaviour. I renamed the reducer to "counter". export it as a counter. import to index.js as "counter" and include in the reducerCombine as "counter". So it is counter everywhere. @vivek Doshi

Comment: I will try to create a demo for the app, hopefully it will not take me another day haha

Comment: @OlegGulevskyy, please check the updated answer, I think that will solve your issue

Comment: Omg indeed, thank you very much! It is totally typo issue.

Comment: @OlegGulevskyy, glad to have help. :) happy coding BTW